# Error named no module named 'matplotlib.pylot' when use numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

When I declare 2 libraries in Python, 2 errors appear:
**import matplotlib.pylot as plt
from scipy import misc**

No module named 'matplotlib.pylot' and module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imread'.
Please help me fix it.
[image]

Comment: Beacuse it is `matplotlib.pyplot`, its a typo.

Comment: Also `imread` doesn't exist in `scipy.misc`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because it's not "matplotlib.*pylot*" but rather "matplotlib.pyplot".

Comment: I'm not using italic font type